# react - Images in public return 404 since added proxy

Tags: svg, proxy, react-tsx

I set my images inside the `public/avatars` and render them via `<img src='avatars/my-image1.svg' />`

my app run on : `http://localhost:3001`

it works fine, but since I added a proxy inside the package.json:

`proxy: http://localhost:3000`

the images return 404 (not found)

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Presumably you need to include the port number in your URLs? `<img src='http://localhost:3000/avatars/my-image1.svg' />`?

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help.

Comment: @r3mainer Do you know if I need to fetch the images (in the client repo within public folder) via localhost:3001(client) or via localhost:3000(server)?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to set the proxy for the endpoint via `src/setupProxy.js` (not via package.json)

and place the following contents in it:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/your_api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:3000',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

link: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually

[image of full instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TzWM.png)

Comment: Hi, Do you know the syntax to add several rules to setupProxy.js ? should i add a module.exports line or only a app.use line or how do i write that?